# JavaScript keypress event late. Can I fix it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, keypress

I use JavaScript keypress event to preview the input in textbox. I am trying to solve the late event issue with setTimeout and SetInterval but both unable to solve the issue.

Can someone show me how I can solve this issue.

Comment: you can start by providing the code you have so far

Comment: Explain *the late event issue* please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using onkeyup or onkeydown instead of keypress event !